# Instance variable modification during runtime using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have been through the below code . Here i am not able to get/set the value of the variable during runtime . Variable value has been taken through console .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ReflectionTest
{
    class Addition
    {
        public  int a = 5, b = 10, c = 20;
        public Addition(int a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Constructor called, a={0}", a);
        }
        public Addition()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
        protected Addition(string str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }

    }

    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //changing  variable value during run time
            Addition add = new Addition();
            Console.WriteLine("a + b + c = " + (add.a + add.b + add.c));
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the variable that you wish to change:");
            string varName = Console.ReadLine();
            Type t = typeof(Addition);
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = t.GetField(varName ,BindingFlags.Public);
            if (fieldInfo != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The current value of " + fieldInfo.Name + " is " + fieldInfo.GetValue(add) + ". You may enter a new value now:");
                string newValue = Console.ReadLine();
                int newInt;
                if (int.TryParse(newValue, out newInt))
                {
                    fieldInfo.SetValue(add, newInt);
                    Console.WriteLine("a + b + c = " + (add.a + add.b + add.c));
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
       }
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: You need to pass your instance to SetValue.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead filedinfo itself is coming as null . So its not even get into  if condition .

Comment: I have supplied an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues.

Firstly, you're passing `BindingFlags.NonPublic`. This won't work. You need to pass `BindingFlags.Public` and `BindingsFlags.Instance` like this:

```
t.GetField(varName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Or, just don't do it at all:

```
t.GetField(varName);
```

You can pass nothing at all because the implementation of `GetField` is this:

```
return this.GetField(name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

So it does it for you.

Also, you need to pass instances of `Addition` to `GetValue` and `SetValue`, like so:

```
Console.WriteLine("The current value of " + 
    fieldInfo.Name + 
    " is " + 
    fieldInfo.GetValue(add) + ". You may enter a new value now:");
//                     ^^^ This
```

..and..

```
fieldInfo.SetValue(add, newInt);
//                 ^^^ This
```

Answer (score 1):

The fields in your class are instance specific and public, yet you are using the noon public binding flag instead of the public binding flag and not applying the instance binding flag (using | for bitwise or).

Comment: Evenif i use BindingFlag.Public , filedinfo is coming as null .
i have edited the question .

Comment: You forgot the | binding flag. Instance in addition to the public.

Comment: ya now its fine . i have to pass Addition clas object into getValue and Setvalue . I have edited my post accordingly .. 
Thankss